# How would I properly do Speech Synthesis in this environment?

Tags: lua, text-to-speech, roblox

I'm trying to make a decent voice synthesis/text to speech system using lua and pre-recorded phonemes based off the CMU dictionary here:

http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/cmudict

How I've done it so far is, once a player inputs text, it goes through each word and gets their phoneme set from here:

http://svn.code.sf.net/p/cmusphinx/code/trunk/cmudict/cmudict-0.7b

It then plays back each phoneme set per word one at a time, with a constant time offset before it plays the next phoneme.

i.e,

```
if Phoneme.TimePosition>=_end-(_end-_start)*0.4 then
```

Phoneme being the sound object corresponding to the phoneme(I recorded the 39 phonemes with my mic and linked a sound object to the respective file) , `_end` being the sound file length and `_start` being 0, of course

Here's the result:

https://streamable.com/8iwnu

While it's not completely terrible, it still sounds pretty bad and I was wondering what else I could do to make this better. I read that Microsoft TTS also uses recordings of humans saying the phonemes to output the sound. And it sounds great.

What can I do? What am I missing? Is this the best I can do with my limitations? I can't actually do any real time sound processing in roblox, or create sounds/write to waveforms or anything, I can only play sound objects linked to a sound file(although I can adjust the pitch, volume, and apply effects such as echo tempo EQ etc.)

Comment: You'd better glue diphones then instead of phonemes, that should give you more smooth transitions. You can get some introduction at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_synthesis#Diphone_synthesis.

Answer (score 0):

As Nikolay Shmyrev mentioned in a comment to your post, a better option is to work with diphones, but that also means you'll require 1521 samples. So what you would typically do is record a corpus of sentences containing all diphones and then automatically (or manually once) segment and label those, storing them as single wavefiles.

That being said, Diphone Synthesis [1] isn't really used a lot anymore. Most older Microsoft TTS voices probably use a more complex unit selection synthesis system [2]. This means you pick units of different sizes (so phones, diphones etc. up to words and full sentences) from a recorded corpus according to a metric that optimizes how well a sample would fit what you want to produce and how well the transition to other samples would be. Signal processing methods are often superimposed to smooth the transitions (or produce other effects).

At the time of writing most modern TTS system employ Deep Learning, either in combination with Unit Selection ("hybrid synthesis") as for Siri [3] or for directly modeling waveforms like the Google/Deepmind Wavenet [4]. Vocoders [5] are often used to either directly produce waveform from acoustic features or to condition models like WaveNet.

Coming back to your constraints.
If you are a developer for the game itself, it should be possible to integrate some existing TTS library and this is probably the best solution.
If your only option is really to play wavefiles, I think your options are really limited to some sort of diphone/unit selection system with a couple of tricks. But even then it might take you quite some effort to get something reasonable (I've been working in speech synthesis for more than 6 years now - it's a much more complex topic than most people might assume at first ;)).

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_synthesis#Diphone_synthesis

[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_synthesis#Unit_selection_synthesis

[3] https://machinelearning.apple.com/2017/08/06/siri-voices.html

[4] https://deepmind.com/blog/wavenet-generative-model-raw-audio/

[5] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocoder